# How can I make program sleep till the tts is going on

Tags: python, python-3.x, sleep

How can I make program sleep till the `tts.Speak` is running.
Means I want to make the program sleep till the `tts.Speak` is working, I have Tried:

```
import time
import androidhelper
droid = androidhelper.Android()
droid.ttsSpeak("System Stopped!!!")
time.sleep(droid.ttsSpeak)
```

It says:

> NameError: global name 'time' is not defined

What can I do please tell.

Comment: Then please update the question with the latest code.

Comment: Try using `from time import sleep` and then just run `sleep` , and see if there is still an error

Answer (score 0):

Since Rahul already solved your problem of `time`. I think the problem you are facing now is because of input `type`. You need to convert your input to integer. Try the following code.

```
import time
import androidhelper
droid = androidhelper.Android()
droid.ttsSpeak("System Stopped!!!")
time.sleep(int(float(droid.ttsSpeak)))
```

Comment: It says:   TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not a 'function"

Comment: @MuhammadSaad could you tell what does `droid.ttsSpeak` do ?